# Odoo: prevent the form from closing?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

is there a way to prevent a wizard form from closing by condition (by clicking on cross or Esc)?

for example if some field is not empty?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
return {"type": "ir.actions.do_nothing"}
```

on your button method.